# Select one row per ID based on two columns

Tags: sql

This is probably really simple, but I've been trying to figure this out for a while, maybe a fresh pair of eyes will/could help.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/557e5a/1

I have this table wherein I need to prioritize selecting Accounts that are Chequing first, and if they don't have a Chequing account, then select the Savings account.

As you can see, PartyID C only has a Savings account, and everyone else has either both, or only a Chequing account.

I tried `SELECT PartyID, MIN(Description), MIN(Number) FROM Table GROUP By PartyID`

and that gave me what I needed for the most part, but for PartyID E, it's returning the Business Savings account instead of their Chequing account.

[image]

The desired output result would be this

[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: Where does the description `E Package Chequing` come from in the result? It's not in the input.

Comment: And if you want `MIN(Number)`, why is it `118` for E instead of `117`?

Comment: yeah pasted the unedited version over from excel.

Comment: @Barmar The output on the min(number) returns 117, the output i wanted is for the description 'Package Chequing' and Number '118'.  Not sure how to get that result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using analytic function `row_number` (*note that analytic functions are supported from MySQL version 8.0 onwards*):

```
select 
    PartyID, 
    Description, 
    Classification, 
    Number 
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by PartyID 
                              order by 
                                case Classification when 'Checking' then 1 when 'Savings' then 2 end,
                                Number desc
                             ) as rn 
  from Table1
) as tab where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a window function to rank the rows within each party ID, ranking `Chequing` before `Savings`.

```
with ranked AS (
  SELECT *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PartyID ORDER by Classification = 'Chequing' DESC, Number) AS rn
  FROM Table1
)

SELECT PartyID, Classification, Description, Number
FROM ranked
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY PartyID
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8r5maCZyYmXmifzjAtftqN/0)